# What does the $'{}' mean in curl command

Tags: bash, curl

I am wondering what does the $ mean in the curl command when I am sending a POST.

e.g. `curl -X POST mydomain.com -d $'{\n"some.*.something": "myvalue"\n}'`

Also I am trying to parameterized the `myvalue` in my shell script, however I am unable to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note it's not really necessary; as far as the consumer of the JSON data will be concerned, `'{"some.*.something": "myvalue"}'` will work exactly the same; the newlines are unnecessary formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$'{\n"some.*.something": "myvalue"\n}'` gets interpreted by the shell before it gets passed to curl.

`$'...'` are so called [ANSI C strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting). They exist in the shell language next to [double-quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes) `"..."` and [single-quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes) `'...'`.

Since the data itself - which seems to be json - contains double quotes, double quoted strings can't be used to wrap the data without escaping the double quotes within the data itself. Meaning it would need to look like this:

```
"{\n\"some.*.something\": \"myvalue\"\n}"
```

Basically single quoted strings could be used to avoid escaping the `"`.

```
'{\n"some.*.something": "myvalue"\n}'
```

But since the data contains the newline escape sequence `\n` and escape sequences won't get expanded in [single quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes), the author of the example in the question used ANSI C strings `$''`.

Using ANSI C strings they get both: They can avoid to escape the double quotes in the data and still have the newline escape sequences getting expanded.

After the shell has expanded it, for curl the data looks like this:

```
{
"some.*.something": "myvalue"
}
```

Further read: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what $'{}' mean. However, I did get `myvalue` to be parameterized.

```
"{\"some.*.something\":\"${myValueParamerterized}\"}"
```

Comment: You should use `jq` to safely create JSON data. Directly substituting variables is dangerous: what if the variable contains quotes, backslashes, or other special characters?